# Disable drag-drop while HTML5 file browse popup is open

Tags: angularjs, html

I am working on an Angular JS application which has  HTML5 file input button and a Drag - Drop area.
I need to disable the drag drop area as long as the file browse popup is open. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you show your code so far? Thanks.

Comment: Is everything not disabled while the dialog is opened? If you are trying to prevent both from working why not make a trivial condition to test. Say onclick of the file input you make the DnD disabled then when not it is enabled.

Comment: Just set a flag. If it's set, the window is open, don't accept. False, the window is closed, accept.

Comment: How do I know when the file browse window is closed? I looked at other threads and could not find any solution to this. OnFocus event did not help as the file input button was getting focus when a file is drag dropped from the file browse window to the browser

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I just made for you, this is an updated Google DnD Controller that I made more advanced plus added the functionality you wanted.

```
window.fileBrowserActive = false; //init the controller to false
function DnDFileController(selector, onDropCallback) {
   var el_ = document.querySelector(selector);//select our element
   var overCount = 0;//over count is 0
   this.dragenter = function(e) 
   {
       e.stopPropagation();//stop propagation and prevent the default action if any
       e.preventDefault();
       overCount++;//increment and assign the overCount var to 1
       if(fileBrowserActive == false)//if the fileBrowserAction is false we can add dropping class
       {
           el_.classList.add('dropping');
       }
       else  //else add error or none at all it's your choice
       {
           el_.classList.add('error');
       }
   };


   this.dragover = function(e) 
   {
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.preventDefault();
   };

   this.dragleave = function(e)
   {
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.preventDefault();
       if (--overCount <= 0) { //we decrement and assign overCount once if it's equal to or less than 0 remove the classes and assign overCount to 0 
          el_.classList.remove('dropping');
          el_.classList.remove('error');  
          overCount = 0;
       }
    };

   this.drop = function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      el_.classList.remove('dropping');
      el_.classList.remove('error');
       if(fileBrowserActive === false)
       {  //if fileBrowserActive is false send the datatranser data to the callback
          onDropCallback(e.dataTransfer);
       }
       else 
       {  //else send false
           onDropCallback(false);
       }
   };
    el_.addEventListener('dragenter', this.dragenter, false);
    el_.addEventListener('dragover', this.dragover, false);
    el_.addEventListener('dragleave', this.dragleave, false);
    el_.addEventListener('drop', this.drop, false);

}
var isFileBrowserActive = function(e){
    fileBrowserActive = true; //once clicked on it is active 
    this.onchange = function(e){ //create the onchange listener
        if(e.target.value !== "") //if the value is not blank we keep it active
        {   //so now user can't DnD AND use the file browser
            fileBrowserActive = true;
        }
        else if(e.target.value == "") //if it is blank means they click cancel most likely
        {
            fileBrowserActive = false;//assign false back
        }  //remove the listener 
        this.removeEventListener('change',this.onchange,false);
    };
    //assign the listener for change
    this.addEventListener('change',this.onchange,false);
};

 var fB = document.getElementById('fileBrowser'); //grab our element for file input
 fB.addEventListener('click',isFileBrowserActive,false); //assign the click event
 var activation = new DnDFileController('#dragNDrop',function(e){ //grab our DnD element
                  console.log(e); //console log the e (either datatransfer || false)
                  });
```

Check out the [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tfze7c2/) to see how this works

Comment: Wanted to add for testing purpose, drag something over the blue square, it'll turn green meaning GOOD TO GO. Then open the filebrowser and move the dialog box, now drag something again it'll turn RED meaning ERROR